# Kafka consumer unable to read data on Windows

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to write a simple Kafka consumer to read the data on a windows machine.
but my consumer is not able to read any data. There are more than 20 messages produced by the producer but none is getting consumed.

Below is my code for the consumer :

```
 Properties properties= new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"my_application");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");

    // properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"earliest");

    //create the consumer

    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer= new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);

    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton("first_topic"));

        ConsumerRecords<String, String> record=consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
        for(ConsumerRecord data: record){
            System.out.println("Key: "+data.key()+" and value: "+data.value());
            System.out.println("Topic: "+data.topic());
            System.out.println("Partition: "+data.partition());
        }
```

The same issue was happening when I was using console to consume the messages using the command :

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --from-beginning --topic first_topic --group my-application
```

I had to use `--partition 0` option explicitly to get the messages.
Is there a way I can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the following property in the code-

```
 `properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")
```

It tells the consumer to read only the latest messages, that is, the messages which were published after the consumer started.

```
`properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
```

When a consumer starts to consume the messages from the partition, it will start to read from the beginning.

Use the following command

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

----group my-application it should be --group my-application

https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Please follow the below steps.

**a. Get the partitions of a topic**

```
./kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test
Topic: test PartitionCount: 1   ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824
    Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

**b. Get the offset of the topic.**

```
/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test --time -1
test:0:11
```

**c. consume the messages of a partition**

```
/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test   --partition 0
```

You can also specify an `--offset` parameter that indicates which offset to start from. If absent, the consumption starts at the end of the partition.

You can also use an GUI based tool to view data in each partition of a topic named kafka tool. http://www.kafkatool.com It’s a tool to manage our kafka cluster.

**Java Code**

```
TopicPartition partition0 = new TopicPartition(topic, 0);
 TopicPartition partition1 = new TopicPartition(topic, 1);
 consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(partition0, partition1));
```

You can get the detailed implementation using java at the following URL.

https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/kafka/manually-assign-partition-to-a-consumer.html

Comment: Thank for the answer. But the behavior is still the same. The record count is still coming out to be 0. I have tried both the offset config but none worked.